# Method to know headphone jack status?

Tags: audio-jack

with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
My hardware has one audio codec connect to chipset by HDA bus for supporting internal speakers and microphone, and another codec by external USB chips with 3.5mm jack for supporting a headset solution. actaully , I can switch them by OS sound page and function is working now. but I can't know USB jack was plugged or not by this sound page. Is there any method to see jack status for ubuntu 20.04 ?? 3rd party GUI was acceptable.
thanks